# What's the meaning of requests in Load-balancer?

Tags: dns, load-balancer

When I read this[article](http://igoro.com/archive/what-really-happens-when-you-navigate-to-a-url/):

there is a term:

> **Load-balancer** is the piece of hardware that listens on a particular IP address and forwards the requests to other servers. Major sites will typically use expensive high-performance load balancers.

there I don't understand the `requests` of "forwards the requests to other servers".

Is it mean the DNS request? or other application layer requests?
Can I name the `Load-balancer` as `DNS Load-balancer`?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

That seems to use the term 'request' both for DNS queries and for HTTP requests, which makes it a bit confusing. Most load balancers however are able to balance all kinds of application protocols, including HTTP, DNS, SMTP, RDP, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of that article, a request is on the application level - as Teun has pointed out, it may be a DNS, an HTTP, or any other request supported by the balancer.

A load balancer's job is to distribute client-side requests to a cluster of servers. It forwards each request to one of the servers (by some policy) and forwards its response back to the initial client.

Many load balancers simply work on the transport layer (L4), so they don't actually distribute application-layer requests, but rather L4 connections. Some protocols like pipelined HTTP can reuse a single connection for multiple requests.